# How to do the mutiple insert into..select query in a single insert statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-insert

I'm having a multiple insert into..select statement as below. If u see, there is only one column value(**Req_Attrname**) is changing in all the three statements.Everything else is same including the `where` conditions.

insert statement 1)

```
insert into details(repo_phyid,repo_type,repo_attrname,repo_Attrvalue
                    ,Req_phyid,Req_type,Req_Attrname,Req_attrvalue) 
select demo.phyid,'Complementary Item','Product Management Responsible',demo.attr_value,
                   tnr.phyid,'Complementary Item','**Product Manager**',demo.attr_value
       From repo_Tnr Tnr,repo_Tnr_Attribute demo 
       Where Tnr.Phyid=demo.Phyid 
             And demo.Attr_Name='Product Management Responsible'
             and tnr.type='Complementary Item'
```

insert statement 2)

```
insert into details(repo_phyid,repo_type,repo_attrname,repo_Attrvalue,
                     Req_phyid,Req_type,Req_Attrname,Req_attrvalue) 
select demo.phyid,'Complementary Item','Product Management Responsible',demo.attr_value,
                   tnr.phyid,'Complementary Item','**Quality Manager**',demo.attr_value
       From repo_Tnr Tnr,repo_Tnr_Attribute demo 
       Where Tnr.Phyid=demo.Phyid 
             And demo.Attr_Name='Product Management Responsible'
             and tnr.type='Complementary Item'
```

insert statement 3)

```
insert into details(repo_phyid,repo_type,repo_attrname,repo_Attrvalue
                    ,Req_phyid,Req_type,Req_Attrname,Req_attrvalue) 
select demo.phyid,'Complementary Item','Product Management Responsible',demo.attr_value
                    ,tnr.phyid,'Complementary Item',**'Depty Engineer**',demo.attr_value
        From repo_Tnr Tnr,repo_Tnr_Attribute demo 
        Where Tnr.Phyid=demo.Phyid 
              And demo.Attr_Name='Product Management Responsible'
              and tnr.type='Complementary Item'
```

What i'm trying here is, if the select returns me 20 rows, first i have to insert that 20 rows with `Product Manager` as value for Req_attrname then i have to insert same 20 rows but with `Quality Manager` and again with `Deputy Engineer` . to accomplish this i'm using 3 insert statement. Like this i'm having 15 to 20 insert statement. Is there a way that can do it in single insert statement? it will help me to decrease the code and increase the readbility. Kindly provide an alternate solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `Req_Attrname` are all constants, you can query all of them from `dual` and `cross join` this result on the original query so you get each row from your query matches with each `Req_Attrname`:

```
INSERT INTO details (repo_phyid,
                     repo_type,
                     repo_attrname,
                     repo_attrvalue,
                     req_phyid,
                     req_type,
                     req_attrname,
                     req_attrvalue) 
SELECT     demo.phyid,
           'Complementary Item',
           'Product Management Responsible',
           demo.attr_value,
           tnr.phyid,
           'Complementary Item',
           req_attrname,
           demo.attr_value
FROM       repo_tnr tnr
JOIN       repo_tnr_tttribute demo ON tnr.phyid = demo.phyid
CROSS JOIN (SELECT '**Product Manager**' AS req_attrname FROM dual
            UNION ALL
            SELECT '**Quality Manager**' AS req_attrname FROM dual
            UNION ALL
            SELECT '**Depty Engineer**'  AS req_attrname FROM dual) t
WHERE      demo.attr_name = 'Product Management Responsible' AND
           tnr.type = 'Complementary Item'
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. :) I have one more doubt. What if those are not constants and i need to pick from some table ? Because i have those scenerio's also. Please help me.

Comment: @Crazy2crack you can just query that table instead of `dual`.